# Comparing two tables - Oracle SQL developer

Tags: sql, oracle, datatables, compare

I am trying to compare two tables in oracle sql developer.
Need to get a list of rows from two tables that are having different C column values but same A and B column values.

Thanks,
Deepa

Comment: Show your efforts so far

Comment: table ddl would be nice. perhaps even some potential inserts for thos tables.

Comment: Sample data and desired results would make the question clearer.

Answer (score 0):

As I interpret the question, you can use `join`

```
select t1.*, t2.*
from table1 t1 join
     table2 t2
     on t1.a = t2. a and t1.b = t2.b
where t1.c <> t2.c;
```

This returns all pairs of rows in the two tables that have matching `a` and `b`, but the `c` value is not the same.

Answer (score 0):

If the C column is some kind of number, you should use the following method and you won't get duplicated occurences:

```
select t1.*,
       t2.*
  from table1 t1,
       table2 t2
 where t1.a = t2.a
   and t1.b = t2.b
   and t1.c < t2.c;
```

Comment: Tip of today: Always use modern, explicit `JOIN` syntax. Easier to write (without errors), easier to read and maintain, and easier to convert to outer join if needed!

Answer (score 0):

Potential answer using the following potential objects .

Table ddl

```
create table a_Table( 
colum1  varchar2(20),
colum2  varchar2(20),
colum3  varchar2(20)
);

create table b_Table( 
colum1  varchar2(20),
colum2  varchar2(20),
colum3  varchar2(20)
);
 --POTENTIAL INSERT --        
INSERT INTO B_TABLE (COLUM1, COLUM2, COLUM3) VALUES ('A', 'A', 'B');
INSERT INTO B_TABLE (COLUM1, COLUM2, COLUM3) VALUES ('A', 'A', 'D');
INSERT INTO A_TABLE (COLUM1, COLUM2, COLUM3) VALUES ('A', 'A', 'C');
INSERT INTO A_TABLE (COLUM1, COLUM2, COLUM3) VALUES ('A', 'A', 'D');




  --QUERY TO FIND THE DIFF --


SELECT
    a.*,
    b.*
FROM
         a_table a
    JOIN b_table b 
    ON a.colum1 = b.colum1
    AND a.colum2 = b.colum2
WHERE   a.colum3 != b.colum3;
```

Comment: Tip of today: Always use modern, explicit `JOIN` syntax. Easier to write (without errors), easier to read and maintain, and easier to convert to outer join if needed!